# Можно ли изменять значения типизированных констант в Delphi

Tags: delphi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильно ли я понимаю, что изменять значение типизированной константы можно только если скорректировать настройки компилятора(или использовать директивы)?

Comment: Вопрос, как я понимаю, риторический ;) В старых версиях настройки не было, менять можно было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, для этого есть три варианта.

**Первый:** в настройках компилятора включить writable constants.

**Второй, полезный для хранения всяких настроек:**

```
unit settings;

interface

const 
  AppSettings: TSettringsRec = ({тут значения по умолчанию});

implementation

var
  LAppSettings: TSettringsRec absolute AppSettings;

// тут можно писать в переменную LAppSettings, а всё остальное приложение будет 
// читать из константы AppSettings.
```

(*) возможно этот вариант будет работать не во всех версиях Delphi.

**Третий - это хак и к использованию не рекомендуется:**

```
type 
  PDate = ^Date;

....
  PDate(@day)^.First := 7;
```